# rename to upper case in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like in Eclipse IDE to rename a variable name / constant / enum type just by switching the case without typing the variable name again.

I am refactoring a long enum with all its types in lower case, and I would like to rename them to upper case without wasting much time typing them again.

I suppose that should be a way to do this, but I do not figure out.

Comment: Select the text and try `CTRL+SHIFT+X` and `CTRL+SHIFT+Y` if you want to convert it back to lowercase again

Answer (score 3):

For similar questions, in Eclipse go to `Window->Preferences->General->Keys`. In this case (pun intended), type `case` in the filter field. You can also set your own key bindings here and the context in which they apply.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse 4.30 (Q4 2023) can help for static constant fields:

> ### [Quick assist to rename constant fields](https://eclipse.dev/eclipse/news/4.30/jdt.php#constant-renaming)
>
> A new quick assist has been added to rename static constant fields to follow a standard syntax using upper-case and underscores rather than camel case.
> To use: select the constant and click CTRL+1.
> For example,
>
> [image: rename constant quick assist -- https://eclipse.dev/eclipse/news/4.30/images/constant-renaming.png]
>
> will offer to rename the constant "`valConstant1`" to "`VAL_CONSTANT1`".